# Rapidly Increasing Storage Usage During Geth Full Node Sync

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am currently synchronizing an Ethereum full node using Geth and have noticed that the storage usage is increasing too rapidly. According to my logs:

```
age=5y6mo2d - 16 may 12:45 pm - 748 gb 
age=5y3mo4h - 17 may 3:16 pm 1.11 tb 
age=5y1mo2d - 18 may 10:40 am 1.32 tb
```

As you can see, the storage used for just 2 months of block data is quite substantial. I am trying to understand this pattern in relation to the total remaining blocks. From the eth.syncing logs:

```
{ currentBlock: 5615753, healedBytecodeBytes: 0, healedBytecodes: 0, healedTrienodeBytes: 0, healedTrienodes: 0, healingBytecode: 0, healingTrienodes: 0, highestBlock: 16121828, startingBlock: 5607195, syncedAccountBytes: 0, syncedAccounts: 0, syncedBytecodeBytes: 0, syncedBytecodes: 0, syncedStorage: 0, syncedStorageBytes: 0 }
```

The currentBlock indicates that there are approximately 11 million more blocks to sync. My concern is about the rapid growth of storage usage and whether the current pace is sustainable given my storage capacity (3.6TB).

I'm seeking clarity on a few points:

- Are my observations of the storage growth pattern accurate, or am I possibly misunderstanding the logs?
- Is there an inconsistency in the block-age to storage ratio, considering that 5 million blocks account for just half a year's difference, and yet there are 11 million more blocks (representing 5.5 years) still to sync?
- Is this expected behavior during a full node sync, or are there ways to manage the storage growth more efficiently?
  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
Geth
Version: 1.11.6-stable

Geth run command

geth --config /mnt/raid/ethdata/config.toml --gcmode full --syncmode full --datadir /mnt/raid/ethdata/mainnet --cache 48000 --cache.trie.journal=0 --cache.gc=0 --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0 --ws --ws.api "eth, net, web3, txpool, personal, debug" --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.port 8546 --ws.origins "*" --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.port 8545 --http.api "eth, web3, net" --verbosity 3 >> /mnt/raid/ethdata/mainnet/eth.log 2>&1
```